# Why does my image slider not automatically start?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I hope to get some help here. I think the solution can be very easy but I can't find the problem.

I created an image slider with changing buttons on click. I have the code from the internet and it works fine. The problem is that the carousel doesn't start automatically on the website starter page. The slideshow loop only starts if I click on the first picture.

This is how my .js code looks like. Regards :)

```
/*SLIDESHOW*/
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlide(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n){
showSlide(slideIndex += n);
}


function currentSlide(n) {
showSlide(slideIndex = n);
}


function showSlide(n){
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides fade");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 3};
if (n < 3) { slideIndex = slides.length};
for (i=0;i<slides.length;i++)



 {
slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) 
  {slideIndex = 1}
for (i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
}

slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
setTimeout(showSlide, 3000);

}
```

Comment: Add your code in document.ready function and try.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your answer. Can you maybe show me how to include this code in my code correctly? Regards :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add your code inside a document.ready function and try,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     //Your Code

});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.